# Saving Jpeg image in C# changes pixels

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, jpeg, steganography

I wrote my own code implementing Steganography project to hide text inside an image. The code works perfectly.

But when I save the image into jpeg file and opening it again, the data is lost, and I get a rubbish result text (as if pixels not saved correctly into the new image)

[image]

But when I save the image in Bmp format, then I can get the hidden text perfectly, as if the pixels are saved correctly into the output image:

[image]

So where is the problem?

Comment: Jpeg compression is a lossy algorithm. So you can't use Jpeg for `Steganography`

Comment: bmp is a very old file format and has very little compression (if any?), you may wish to save as .png though

Comment: @I4V Can I save as Jpeg without compression?

Comment: As @I4V pointed out, you should not use jpg as an output format, if you modify individual pixels to store hidden values. png is also lossy, so bmp would probably be the best choice.

Comment: @HamzehSoboh then it is `bmp` etc..

Comment: ...And bmp is a lossless format, so steganography works.  You might use other lossless formats, like .png or .gif.

Comment: I've just tried PNG format, and it's working. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: You can use JPEG format, but you will need to add the coded message at the entropy coding stage, not as source pixels.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use lossless jpeg, there are few libraries that do that (Pegasus, LeadTools)
If you can't use any of them then you need to use PNG. Stock Jpeg compression in .Net is lossy, so the pixel won't be the same.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, since PNG size is relatively large.

Comment: albattran, do you know the size when using their lossless option? Is it really smaller then png?

Comment: @I4V so we will only win the extension.

Comment: @HamzehSoboh most picture viewers/browsers don't care about extensions. So no win on extension. Try to rename your bmp file to jpg and cick on it.

Comment: @I4V I agree with you. PNG is better for this purpose.

Comment: Hi I4V, Yes, Jpeg LS is usually smaller than PNG as it is more efficient. Having said that, PNG can be more efficient than jpeg in solid colour images (like computer generated icons etc) so it really depends on what you are using it for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use steganography with lossy compression methods, like JPEG, you're existing algorithm is obviously not robust.

To see an example of how you *can* use steganography in such circumstances, take a look at [the open source F5-steganography project](http://code.google.com/p/f5-steganography/)